# SQL Date Logic Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having problems understanding how to get the Where clause to work with this date structure.

Here is the principal logic.  I want data only from previous March 1 onward and ending on yesterdays date.

Example #1:
So today is Feb 13, 2015 This would mean I need data between (**2014-03-01** and **2015-02-12**)

Example #2:
Say today is March 20, 2015 This This would mean I need data between (**2015-03-01** and **2015-03-19**)

The where logic might work but it doesn't like to convert '3/1/' + year.  But I'm not sure how else to express it.  The first clause is fine its the Case section that is broken.

**Query**

```
    SELECT [Request Date], [myItem]
    FROM myTable
    WHERE [Request Date] < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102)
        AND [Request Date] = CASE WHEN 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) <
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), '3/1/' + DATEPART ( year , GETDATE()) , 114)
        THEN [Request Date] > CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), '3/1/' + DATEPART ( year , GETDATE()-365) , 114)
        ELSE [Request Date] > CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), '3/1/' + DATEPART ( year , GETDATE() , 114)
        END
```

I have also tried

```
AND [Request Date] = CASE WHEN 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) <
            '3/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEPART ( YYYY , GETDATE()))
        THEN [Request Date] > '3/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEPART ( YYYY , GETDATE()-364))
        ELSE [Request Date] > '3/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEPART ( YYYY , GETDATE()))
        END
```

Comment: Can you specify the type of SQL you are using?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified this.   This is SQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `where` clause.

```
WHERE [Request Date] 
         BETWEEN Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), Year(Getdate())-1)+ '-03-01' AS DATE)
                    AND Getdate() - 1
```

Here `Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), Year(Getdate())-1)+ '-03-01' AS DATE)` will fetch the first day of march month. With that add -1 year to get the starting point.

`Getdate() - 1` will define the ending point

Comment: This code just creates the previous year based on the beginning of this month, and does not split on march 1st at all..

Comment: This code fails past march of this year. It always pulls the previous year not the previous march 1st.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to create datetime variables for the @from - @to range but if this is for a view I guess you have to do it in the where clause.

```
SELECT [Request Date], [myItem]
    FROM myTable
    WHERE [Request Date] < cast(GETDATE() as date)
        AND [Request Date] >= CASE WHEN 
            GETDATE() < CONVERT(datetime, '3/1/' + cast(Year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)))
        THEN CONVERT(datetime, '3/1/' + cast(Year(GETDATE()) - 1 as varchar(4)))
        ELSE CONVERT(datetime, '3/1/' + cast(Year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)))
        END
```

Comment: Other then the Type O varchar...this worked perfect.  Thanks dotjoe

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Always from Mar 1st onwards, previous year if it's now Mar 1 or earlier, and otherwise this year.

```
SELECT [Request Date], [myItem]
FROM myTable
WHERE [Request Date] >= dateadd(month, 2, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, dateadd(month, -2, dateadd(day, -1, getdate()))), 0))
and [Request Date] < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

First it deducts one day, so that March 1 isn't taking the same year, then it deducts 2 months for getting those dates for previous year, then it rounds it to the year, and then it adds 2 months to get to Mar 1.

Comment: This is a great technique and will work as the year progresses.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, I'd compute the lower bound like this:

```
add_months( trunc( add_months( sysdate, -2 ), 'YEAR'), 2 )
```

In other words - subtract two months, round down to the start of the year, then add two months.

Hopefully, you can convert this to use appropriate TSQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

Lets work with some test data:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = '3/13/2015'
```

Going to declare some variable we will set:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
```

In this code, I check to see if we are before or after march 1st, and if so we will use either the previous year, or this year for the starting point (fiscal year?)

```
SELECT @StartDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @MyDate) < 3 THEN
    DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @MyDate) - 1, 0))
    ELSE
    DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @MyDate), 0))
    END,
    @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @MyDate), 0)
```

Here is the output:
    SELECT @StartDate AS Start, @EndDate AS EndDate

```
Start                   EndDate
2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 2015-03-13 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a fairly generic user-defined function that does what I need, thus:

```
create function dbo.start_of_fiscal_year
(
  @today date ,
  @fiscal_year_start_month int
)
returns date
as
begin
  set @today = case coalesce(@today,'')
                 when '' then current_timestamp
                 else         @today
               end
  declare @month_start             date = dateadd(day,1-datepart(day,@today),@today)
  declare @fiscal_month_number     int  = case sign( datepart(month,@month_start) - @fiscal_year_start_month )
                                            when -1 then 13
                                            else          1
                                          end
                                        + ( datepart(month,@month_start) - @fiscal_year_start_month )
  declare @fiscal_year_start       date = dateadd(month,1-@fiscal_month_number,@month_start)

  return @fiscal_year_start
end
go
```

Once you have that you can say things like

```
declare @today    date = current_timetamp
declare @fy_start date = start_of_fiscal_year(@today,3)

select *
from dbo.foo t
where t.report_date >= @fy_start
  and t.report_date <  @today
```

or even

```
select fiscal_year = datepart(year,start_of_fiscal_year(t.report_date,3)) , count(*)
from dbo.foo t
group by datepart(year,start_of_fiscal_year(t.report_date,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lower bound should be this. You just need to offset the year when month is less than 3 (March).

```
dateadd(
    yy,
    year(current_timestamp) - 1900 + case when month(current_timestamp) < 3 then -1 else 0 end,
    '19000301'
)
```

There's no reason to mess around with strings and this consolidates the logic very concisely. I'm also guessing that when current date is March 1 that you want to query the full previous year. So you'll want to adjust the test slightly.

```
case when (month(dateadd(dd, -1, current_timestamp)) < 3 ...
```

And just for fun:

```
dateadd(mm, (12-month(current_timestamp-1))/10*-12+2, cast(year(current_timestamp) as char(4)));
```